# Can 国体 refer to "prefectural" as well as "national"?

Tags: meaning, sports

If `国体` is used in conjunction with a prefecture name like [山口国体](http://www.choruru.pref.yamaguchi.lg.jp/), does that mean "The National Athletic Meet that is being held in Yamaguchi", or the "The Yamaguchi Prefectural Athletic Meet"?

The only definition I can find for `国体` (in the context of a sports meet) is that it's the *National* Athletic Meet ([goo](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/all/%E5%9B%BD%E4%BD%93/m0u/)), but `国` can have a meaning of "region" or "hometown" as well as "nation" ([goo](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/all/%E5%9B%BD/m0u/)), so I'm unsure as to what it can mean in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the dictionary says, 国体 in this context is an abbreviation of 国民体育大会 ([National Sports Festival](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Sports_Festival_of_Japan)).  山口国体 means the National Sports Festival held in Yamaguchi, in the same way as “London Olympics” means the Olympic Games held in London.